# Making a program that makes a computer automatically boot usb

Tags: boot, live-usb, bios

Is there any way that I can program my ubuntu bootable usb so that when I turn on a computer (PC or Mac), and the bootable usb is plugged in, it automatically boots into the usb? I am making the ubuntu bootable usb for someone and I want it to be as simple as possible to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can do it. The answer lies in the **BIOS boot priority order**.

Go into your BIOS (by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>) and go to the "**Boot**" sub menu.

There, you can find the boot-order. To boot from a CD/DVD/LiveUSB, you will need to move the boot medium to the **top** of the boot priority list. This is usually done by highlighting the boot device (here,your LiveUSB) and then pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd> to move the highlighted device up/down.

Get the bootable medium to the top (in this case, your LiveUSB), Save and Exit changes. Your copy of Ubuntu will now boot from the USB whenever it is plugged in **before** the computer is booted.

Using a mac, you need to hold down the **Options** button before the boot to access the LiveUSB.

Comment: I meant is there a way that the person using the flash drive won't actually have to go into the BIOS and do all of that, but only have to plug in the usb and turn the computer on.

Comment: It is a one time process, after which you can boot the USB every time it is plugged in without having to go into the BIOS.

Comment: @DaniM.Smith Booting is something that is handled within the BIOS outside of Ubuntu. You need to have the person you give the flash drive to change their boot order. What you are asking for cannot be done and is impossible. The boot order must be changed before booting from the flash drive and there's nothing that can be done about it.